# Algorithm - Best way to determine dimensions for an image size based off its height and width?

Tags: javascript, image, algorithm

I have a bunch of images I am parsing and I have access to their url, height, and width.

I want to place these images in a photo grid that has three different objects of set height and width. I am trying to come up with a good way to place each image in each "class" of item based off its dimensions and which one it would "fit" best with so it is not stretched.

For example:

```
   var imageSource = //source of image;
   var imageHeight = //height of image;
   var imageWidth = //width of image;
   var imageClass = bestClass(imageHeight, imageWidth);

   function bestClass(height, width){
        var classes = ["250,500", "500,500", "300,400"];

        //do some magic to determine which class is the best dimensions for this image in a photo grid. 
   }
```

I wanted to post this question to see if there was any magic built in that helped me out here before I dug into finding the mean difference between height, width and comparing it to the nearest "bin" or whatever...

Comment: Between the `1x2` (that's right - 1px by 2px) image and `249x500` - which would fit the `250x500` better?

Answer (score 3):

As you have answers that technically achieve what you are after I thought I'd put it to you differently:

Is squeezing a 300x500 image into a 250x500 space really acceptable? There will still be distortions.

The ideal answer would be to restructure your data to put some constraints on image dimension ratio, either when images are inserted into the system or run some image processing to crop images to the correct ratio. Note that `background-size: cover;` may help here, and place the image into the background (`background-size` only works on `background` images, not `<img />` elements). Even better than constraining resolution would be to constrain size to the exact sizes you want.

Ideally you'd probably want to change your presentation layer to work with your data (which is arbitrarily sized), but, if that is not an option, you have to try and manipulate your data to match how you want to present. Stretched or squeezed images are never going to look good.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using the ratio height/width.

```
 var ratio = (imageHeight/imageWidth);
 if ( Math.abs(ratio - 250/500) <= Math.abs(ratio - 500/500) && Math.abs(ratio - 250/500) <= Math.abs(ratio - 300/400){
console.log("best is 250/500")
}
else if ( Math.abs(ratio - 500/500) <= Math.abs(ratio - 250/500) && Math.abs(ratio - 500/500) <= Math.abs(ratio - 300/400){
console.log("best is 500/500")
}
else{console.log("best is 300/400")}
```

**Update:** If you dont want to be any distortions and just find the perfect size to fit the images in these classes use the image ratio and the differece between the class ratio like this:

```
var ratio = (imageHeight/imageWidth);
if ( Math.abs(ratio - 250/500) <= Math.abs(ratio - 500/500) && Math.abs(ratio - 250/500) <= Math.abs(ratio - 300/400){
    var dif = ratio-0.5;
    if(dif<=0){
       var newImageWidth = 500;
       var newImageHeight = 500*ratio
    }
    else{
       var newImageWidth = 500 - (500*dif);
       var newImageHeight = 250;
    }
}
else if ( Math.abs(ratio - 500/500) <= Math.abs(ratio - 250/500) && Math.abs(ratio - 500/500) <= Math.abs(ratio - 300/400){
console.log("best is 500/500");
    var dif = ratio-1;
    if(dif<=0){
       var newImageWidth = 500;
       var newImageHeight = 500*ratio
    }
    else{
       var newImageWidth = 500 - (500*dif);
       var newImageHeight = 500;
    }
}
else{console.log("best is 300/400")
    var dif = ratio-0.75;
    if(dif<=0){
       var newImageWidth = 400;
       var newImageHeight = 400*ratio
    }
    else{
       var newImageWidth = 400 - (400*dif);
       var newImageHeight = 300;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the height/width ratio:

```
var func = function bestClass(height, width){
    var classes = [{ Width: 250, Height: 500} , { Width: 500, Height: 500}, { Width: 300, Height: 400}];
    var minDist = 1;
    var ratio = height / width;
    var index = 0;
    for(var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        var dist = Math.abs((classes[i].Height / classes[i].Width) - ratio);
        if (dist < minDist) {
            minDist = dist;
            index = i;
        }
    }
    return classes[index];
}
var result = func(100,100);
```

Comment: How is this different from my answer?